# Is there a way to say if a number is greater than or less than in python?

Tags: python

Im trying to find a way to say that 'if the number a user picks is below 1 or above 20, then print "invalid input"'.

I'm using this for a number guessing game and its to find numbers that aren't in the range of 1 to 20, so that they do not count as guesses.

I have tried:

```
if userNum < 1

    print("invalid input")


if userNum > 20

    print("invalid input")
```

I have also tried this:

```
if 1 > userNum > 20

    print("invalid input")
```

Comment: Topic covered by thousands of post on SO and on other websites/tutorials.

Comment: The operators `>` and `<` compare numbers just as you would expect. If something unexpected happens, then you might be comparing integers with strings (i.e. you forgot to convert your user input to `int`)

Comment: It should be noted that even though some answers are using `or` for some reason, it's not necessary. Your second way is correct and idiomatic; you're just missing a colon on the line.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing a colon after the condition.
Try this

```
if 1 > userNum or userNum > 20:
     print("invalid input")
```

Comment: Im actually stupid... I legit reminded my friend (who is working on the same project) to not forget the colons......................... Thank you ;)

Comment: Also this expression is AND not OR, it checks if number is greater than AND less than, the question asks for a python expression to say if a number is greater than OR less than.

Comment: @nickl is right. I've updated the snippet.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to make sure that your user input is a number, not a string.

As soon as you are comparing numbers, you can use < and > to test for smaller/greater.

```
if userNum > 20 or userNum < 1:
    print("invalid input")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def funcCmp(num):
    if num < 0 or num > 20:
        print ("Invalid")

funcCmp(21)
funcCmp(-1)
```

Simple or operator does your condition checking ! Try with above